# TLS with NULL chipersuite

Tags: tls

In the case of using a cipher suite with all algorithms NULL  e.g.: TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL the protection against replay, swapping and filtering is guaranteed?
(I am talking about message protection, not handshake's one)

Because I have seen that the MAC uses a sequence number, so maybe this is used against replay. If I do not calculate the MAC our TLS fragments are vulnerable to replay, swapping and filtering?
Or the fact that we are using a reliable transmission protocol avoid that ( and in this case what's the point of using a sequence number in the calculation of MAC)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: although protocol related questions are on topic here, this one is probably better at place at security.SO, and it already has [an Q/A](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/135998/2651) which I regard as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` the protection against replay, swapping and
> filtering is guaranteed?

No. The [NULL-cipher suite makes no guarantees at all and it is explicitely forbidden in the RFC that two parties negotiate this cipher suite](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-75), the only reason for its existence is to run the handshake protocol.

> Because I have seen that the MAC uses a sequence number, so maybe this
> is used against replay.

The *TLS record layer* [indeed does use a sequence number which is covered by the MAC authentication to prevent reordering attacks.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3)

> If I do not calculate the MAC our TLS fragments are vulnerable to
> replay, swapping and filtering?

Yes, if you don't use a MAC of some kind (either application layer or transport layer) you have no guarantees regarding authenticity / integrity of the data and thus are prone to such attacks.

> Or the fact that we are using a reliable transmission protocol avoid
> that [...]?

TLS *usually* runs over TCP or a similar relieable protocol, but it is not a requirement. And note especially that such "reliable" protocols are only designed to protect from network errors, such as random transmission. They are *not* designed to survive a malicious / targeted attack which is why we have cryptographic transport protocols like TLS.